# How to use a macro in linux C inline assembly

Tags: c, linux, macros, inline-assembly

I want to call an address that is determined by other configuration result. And that call is in an inline assembly.

Currently, it's like this and is manually modified:

```
asm volatile ("call 0xc0200c20\n\t");
```

My question is can I write it like this?

```
#define CALL_ADDR 0xC0200c20

asm volatile ("call CALL_ADDR\n\t");
```

Thanks!

Comment: `asm volatile("call %P0\n\t" :: "p"(CALL_ADDR))` would do - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965114/gcc-inline-assembly-using-modifier-p-and-constraint-p-over-m-in-linux-kern for the `P` modifier. Warning: using `call` from within inline assembler means you'll have to "bracket" it with code saving/restoring registers. The details of that depend on the ABI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ordinary string concatenation should do the trick, with two wrapper macros to create a stringified version of the value:

```
#define QUAUX(X) #X
#define QU(X) QUAUX(X)

asm volatile ("call " QU(CALL_ADDR) "\n\t");
```

Comment: Seems doesn't work. error: stray ‘#’ in program   error: expected ‘:’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant

Comment: @xiaogw: Absolutely right, sorry about that. You need a separate macro to do the stringification. I had mentally blocked out that step...

Comment: That works! Thanks man. But why we have to use a separate macro for string connection in this case?

Comment: @xiaogw: You can try it yourself in phases and see what comes out of the preprocessor... basically, you need one macro to evaluate the original macro, and the other to stringify. If you just say `QUAUX(CALL_ADDR)`, you get `"CALL_ADDR"`, whereas `QU(CALL_ADDR)` becomes `QUAUX(0xC0200c20)`.

Answer (score 2):

Promoting my comment to an answer:

The `P` modifier for gcc's inline assembly operands stops the compiler from emitting 'constant-indicating prefixes' in the generated assembly code. See the linked reference for a more verbose explanation, quoting Linus.

If you've tried:

```
#define CALL_ADDR 12345678
asm volatile("call %0\n\t" :: "i"(CALL_ADDR));
```

you noticed you get an error from the assembler, because the generated code says `call $12345678` and that's not valid assembly syntax. Using `%P0` instead makes the compiler *not* emit the `$` at the beginning, and it's fine.

There's no need to work with preprocessor string concatenation here - the disadvantage of that is, as you've found, that "nesting" (two levels of macros) is needed so that the `CALL_ADDR` is expanded before the concatenation is done.

Comment: at least with gcc-arm-8.3 %0 seems ok, and %P0 doesn't work.