# What does %P stand for in gcc inline assembly

Tags: assembly

In Linux kernel `linux/arch/x86/boot/main.c`, I found a piece of inline asm code:

```
asm("leal %P1(%%esp),%0"
        : "=r" (stack_end) : "i" (-STACK_SIZE));
```

This code snippet is pretty simple, but `%P1` confused me. I checked some assembly language tutorials, but found nothing about this.

So, can anyone give me some pieces of clue about this?

Comment: Don't quote me, but I believe on some versions of _GCC_ the `P` size operand prefix takes an immediate value and strips off the `$` sign so that the value can be used for x86 displacement values. If you just used `%1` the output would have looked like `leal $stackdisp(%esp)`. (where stackdisp was the value of operand 1). If the `$` would have been emitted the assembler would have complained about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc inline assembly using modifier "P" and constraint "p" over "m" in Linux kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965114/gcc-inline-assembly-using-modifier-p-and-constraint-p-over-m-in-linux-kern)

Comment: Part of your confusion no doubt comes from the fact that the `P` modifier is undocumented (shame on linux for using undocumented compiler features).  In general, @MichaelPetch has this right: It turns off the 'decorations' gcc might be tempted to apply to %1 like @PLT and BYTE PTR (feel free to scan for 'P' in the source: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/i386/i386.c).  Given the "i" constraint, I'd really expect this to be written using the (documented!) `%c1` modifier, but there may be history here.

Answer (score 5):

The `P` output modifier is unofficially documented in a comment in [gcc/config/i386/i386.md](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/i386/i386.md?view=log):

```
;; The special asm out single letter directives following a '%' are:
...
;; P -- if PIC, print an @PLT suffix.
;; p -- print raw symbol name.
```

The upper-case `P` modifier probably isn't what is wanted here, but when not compiling PIC (Position Independent Code), then it acts like the lower-case `p` modifier. The intent to prevent the compiler from emitting the operand using the format normally used for immediate values, which wouldn't work here. As David Wohlferd said it would be a better idea to use the `c` modifier, which is [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers) and is meant specifically to handle immediate values. Mind you this code was probably written before the `c` modifier was documented, as for a long time none of the modifiers were documented.

Given that the inline assembly statement is only executed once at boot time, performance doesn't matter, so I wouldn't have bothered trying to be smart by using LEA. You can avoid the operand modifiers completely with something simple like:

```
 char *stack_pointer;
 asm ("mov %%esp, %0" : "=r" (stack_pointer));
 stack_end = stack_pointer - STACK_SIZE;
```